# If-else in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

Fix this:

```
for n in range(1,8): 
    print(n) 
    if(n>=2 & n<=5): 
        print("This Number is either 2,3,4 or 5\n")
    else: 
        print("This Number is "+n)
```

Comment: We don't write code for you, but we can try to find mistakes. Your code is not formatted and Python really needs formatting. Also, & isn't used in Python. You just use `and`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As pointed out by others, your question is a bit unclear. We do not "fix this", we can find errors. But you need to format with indents and as code, because python heavily relies on indentation and many of us (myself included) have struggled quite a bit with lacking or faulty indents. But if you format it, then you might get some more answers. Currently, several people have answered. But in order to get answers later, please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and be more precise than "Fix this:". Best regards, norway-yv

Answer (score 3):

Use `and`.
`and` is a Logical AND that returns True if both the operands are true whereas `&` is a bitwise operator in Python

```
for n in range(1,8): 
    print(n) 
    if(n >= 2 and n <= 5): 
        print("This Number is either 2,3,4 or 5\n") 
    else: 
        print("This Number is ", + n)
```

Comment: To prevent excess spaces, I would not write `print("This Number is ", + n)`, as that gives two spaces between "is" and n. It is better to use `print("This Number is " + n)`, where you  only end up with one space.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `&` is `bitwise` and operator while `and` is used for logical and operator.
**2.** You need to convert `integer` to `string` for concatenation.

Corrected code:

```
for n in range(1,8): 
    print(n) 
    if(n>=2 and n<=5): 
        print("This Number is either 2,3,4 or 5\n")
    else: 
        print("This Number is "+str(n))
```